# How to pull specific part of a line from a curl response

Tags: php, linux

I run:
curl -tags example.website.com | grep "123"

response:

```
this-line-is-super-long-123-this-line-is-long
```

how do I pull out the "123" only from the curl response?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried your self? What was your approach?

Comment: Hi, yes I had tried grep -Po has Timur suggested, but the grep command on my mac does not have the -P option available so it gave me an error.  I have installed ggrep and will try that when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep -Po` like so:

```
grep -Po '\d+'
```

or in your case,

```
grep -Po '123'
```

Comment: Oh, i see my issue was the grep on my mac terminal did not have -P option available.  using ggrep now seems like it might fix this issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that additional switch `-o` is enough!

For example, if the first part of the command below (`echo "this-line-is-super-long-123-this-line-is-long"`) mocks what you get from the output of the `curl -tags example.website.com`
This will give you what you need:

```
echo "this-line-is-super-long-123-this-line-is-long" | grep -o 123
```